# how to install postgresql in oracle linux 7.2

Tags: linux, postgresql

I'm trying to work with postgresql but i had these problems when I tried to install it in Oracle Linux 7.2 kernel 3.10.0-327

after using this command to compile the source:

./configure --with-openssl

I have this error:

```
checking for main in -lm... yes
checking for library containing setproctitle... no
checking for library containing dlopen... -ldl
checking for library containing socket... none required
checking for library containing shl_load... no
checking for library containing getopt_long... none required
checking for library containing crypt... -lcrypt
checking for library containing shm_open... -lrt
checking for library containing shm_unlink... none required
checking for library containing fdatasync... none required
checking for library containing sched_yield... none required
checking for library containing gethostbyname_r... none required
checking for library containing shmget... none required
checking for library containing readline... no
configure: error: readline library not found
If you have readline already installed, see config.log for details on the
failure.  It is possible the compiler isn't looking in the proper directory.
Use --without-readline to disable readline support.
[root@localhost postgresql-9.5.1]# brew
bash: brew: command not found...
[root@localhost postgresql-9.5.1]# find readline
find: ‘readline’: No such file or directory
[root@localhost postgresql-9.5.1]# yum install readline
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
```

pgdg95                                                                                                                                                        | 3.6 kB  00:00:00
(1/2): pgdg95/7Server/x86_64/group_gz                                                                                                                         |  333 B  00:00:00
(2/2): pgdg95/7Server/x86_64 /primary_db                                                                                                                       | 127 kB  00:00:00

```
Package readline-6.2-9.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[root@localhost postgresql-9.5.1]#
```

readline is already installed , i do not understand why i have the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just found a solution for that:

this command:

> yum install readline-devel
>
> yum install zlib-devel

solved my problem

Comment: Same problem and solution in Debian/ubuntu